# Entity Framework - Update and Delete at same time

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I want to update the record and delete at the same time in Entity Framework.

Can we do this ? or Is it the straight way, first update the record and then delete it ?

My scenario:

I want to delete a record. Before deleting that record, I want to add a comment(which is column in my table), why are we deleting that record.

If you think, why do we add a comment while anyway we are deleting that record, here is what we are doing.

If any change is made to that record, there is a trigger which creates a log record in audit table. So, we want to log that comment.

My only concern with update and deleting by using two commands is it will create two log records.

Comment: I'm not sure how this trigger works, but couldn't you just filter out logs caused by deleting in this specific instance? That way you can still use two commands but only the update will be logged.

Comment: Alternatively, you could call a stored procedure for the delete, which would delete the record and update the audit trail with the comment, eliminating the need for the delete trigger.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update a record and simultaneously delete it in the same operation in SQL Server, whether you use Entity Framework or not.  It's certainly possible to update and then delete it in the context of the same *transaction*, but those are still two separate SQL operations and your logging trigger will fire both times.

If it is possible to modify the logging, you could likely write trigger code with special logic to ensure you only have one log entry, but you will have to address it at that level rather than at the database operation level.